# Equality operator returns true for unequal values

Tags: java, equality

I have two variables y and z of type `double` and `long`. My problem is the equality operator returns true for them even if they have unequal values as you can see in the code snippet below:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        double y = (double) Long.MAX_VALUE;
        System.out.println(y);//9.223372036854776E18
        long z = Long.MAX_VALUE - 1;
        System.out.println(z);//9223372036854775806
        System.out.println(y == z);//=============true
    }
}
```

My query is if z has one value less than y, why `y==z` is returning true?

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Tried printing those values?

Comment: Yes, they both are different

Comment: Any long value greater than `2^53 - 1` cannot be exactly represented as a double.

Comment: Try printing `(double) z` and `y`.

Comment: I have updated the code and seems it is quite different not by magnitude of 1 but huge difference ...:( strange i missing something here

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is a duplicate lurking here too somewhere :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things happened here.

1. In `double == long`, the `long` is [promoted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) to a `double`. The expression `y == z` evaluates the same as `(double) Long.MAX_VALUE == (double) (Long.MAX_VALUE - 1)`.
2. `double` only has 53 bits precision. When converting a long > 2<sup>53</sup> to double, the least-significant bits will be rounded, making `(double) Long.MAX_VALUE` (= 2<sup>63</sup> - 1) and `(double) (Long.MAX_VALUE - 1)` becoming the same value.

Answer (score 5):

To evaluate `y == z`, Java has to promote `z` to a double.

Some long values greater than `2^53 - 1` cannot be exactly represented in a double.

`(double) Long.MAX_VALUE` *does* equal `(double) (Long.MAX_VALUE - 1)`, because double doesn't have enough precision to represent the two values distinctly.

You can see the required delta (as in `Long.MAX_VALUE - delta`) to get a different floating point value using `Math.nextDown`:

```
double delta = y - Math.nextDown(y);
```

This yields 1024.